# d3 chart not updating properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a stacked bar chart. I created a data object using d3.stack, which I bind to the "g" element to handle the proper fill. Then I want to access the lower levels of the data structure to draw the rectangles. This works great the first time, but for some reason, it's not updating when I select new data. The data object "stackedData" is being updated each time, but I can't figure out why that's not updating the 'rect' as well. Thank you for the help!

```
        invalid_svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'invalid-group')
        .selectAll('g')
        .data(stackedData)
        .join(
            enter=>{
                enter.append('g')
                    .attr('fill', d=>colorScale(d.key))
                    // .attr('transform', 'translate(45, 0)')
                    .transition()
                        .duration(this.transition_time)
            },
            update=>{
                update
                .transition()
                    .duration(this.transition_time)
                .attr('fill', d=>colorScale(d.key))
            },
            exit=>{exit.transition()
                    .duration(this.transition_time)
                .remove()
            }
        )
        d3.select('.invalid-group').selectAll('g')
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(d=> d)
            .join(
                enter=>{
                    enter.append('rect')
                        .attr('x', d=>scaleX(d.data.database))
                        .attr('y', d=>scaleY(d[1] || 0))
                        .attr('height', d=>{
                            console.log(d)
                            return scaleY(d[0]) - scaleY(d[1]) || 0; })
                        .attr('width', scaleX.bandwidth())
                        .transition()
                            .duration(this.transition_time)
                },
                update=>{
                    update.transition()
                            .duration(this.transition_time)
                        .attr('x', d=>{
                            console.log(d)
                            return scaleX(d.data.database)})
                        .attr('y', d=>scaleY(d[1] ? d[1]: 0))
                        .attr('height', d=>{return scaleY(d[0]) - scaleY(d[1]) || 0; })
                        .attr('width', scaleX.bandwidth())
                },
                exit=>{
                    exit.remove()
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your code:

1.Append a new `g` with class `invalid-group`:

```
   invalid_svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'invalid-group')
```

2.Perform a join with a new data array to enter new child `g` elements:

```
   .selectAll('g')
    .data(stackedData)
    .join(...
```

3.Select the *first* element with class `invalid-group` and select each child `g`:

```
  d3.select('.invalid-group').selectAll('g')
```

4.Perform a data join with the bound data of each child `g` of the *first* element with class `invalid-group`:

```
 .selectAll('rect')
        .data(d=> d)
        .join(
```

Because step 1 appends a new `g` each iteration, step 2 only ever enters elements: there are no child elements in the newly appended `g` to update. New data is only ever appended to these new `g` elements.

On every iteration other than the first, step 3 ignores these newly joined/entered child `g` elements because it only selects those appended in the first iteration (`d3.select('.invalid-group')` returns the first matching element - which is the `g` appended on the first iteration), and finally step 4 re-binds the data that was originally bound to the children of the `g` appended in step one on the first iteration. This data is never updated, so the rectangles never get new bound datums.

Assuming this code is in an update function, remove the `invalid_svg.append('g')` in step one and do this appending once outside of the update function. Either re-select it to conduct the join in step 2 or use a variable to hold it.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly right. I was just not following what was actually happening with that group at first.

Comment: @Andrew-Reid and @darkwing I'm facing the same issue but wasn't as quick to find a solution.  I declared my variables, appended `g` and assigned a class outside the function, then `.selectAll` and `.join` `g` back in the function, which works for the initial chart but does not work in my update function, where I `.selectAll` and `.join` `g` as well.  Do I need to add an extra piece to the variable declaration outside the function?

Comment: Gregg, it's hard to say what the problem is without seeing your code. Did you remember to bind the data to the element within the function as well?