# How do I manage groups for a grouped bar chart with a dropdown to update the chart in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having an issue updating a group bar chart similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045500/d3-chart-not-updating-properly) but either the proposed solution doesn't work for me or I'm misunderstanding.

I'm fairly certain my issue is with the way I'm managing groups but I can't pinpoint what needs to be changed.  My initial chart works and then when I update the dropdown, only the first group of the grouped bars updates.

My initial chart code (`subgroups` is made up of Y1 and Y2, the two column names of the numbered data, see sample data at bottom):

```
var initialGraph = function(selectedCrime) {
  
      var dataInit = data.filter(d => d.Crime == selectedCrime)
  
        // Show the bars, Cases
    var cases = svg
                .append("g")
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(dataInit.filter(d => d.Count == "Cases"))
                .join("g")
                  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.Zone)}, 0)`)
                .selectAll("rect")
                .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
                  .enter()
                  .append("rect")
                  .attr(...
```

And my update function:

```
var updateGraph = function(selectedCrime) {

  var dataFilter = data.filter(d => d.Crime == selectedCrime)

    var cases = svg
          .data(dataFilter.filter(d => d.Count == "Cases"))
          .selectAll("rect.cases2")
          .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
                    .attr(...
```

My best guess is that I need to `.merge` or `.join` somewhere in the update function but all of the iterations I've tried either produce an error or have no effect at all.  Any help is much appreciated.

Sample data:

```
Crime,Count,Zone,Y1,Y2
Crime1,Cases,Zone1,43,58
Crime1,Arrests,Zone1,32,35
Crime2,Cases,Zone1,50,58
Crime2,Arrests,Zone1,20,18
Crime2,Cases,Zone2,80,79
Crime2,Arrests,Zone2,5,4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, finally got it to work by 1. removing the first function `initialGraph` and filter `dataInit`, 2. adding an `&& d.Crime` statement in the `.data.filter` to replace the initial filter, and 3. splitting each of the declarations into two declarations:

```
var cases = svg
                .append("g")
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(dataInit.filter(d => d.Count == "Cases"))
                .join("g")
                  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.Zone)}, 0)`)
                .selectAll("rect")
```

to

```
var cases = svg
                .append("g")
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(dataInit.filter(d => d.Count == "Cases"))
                .join("g")
                  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.Zone)}, 0)`)
   var cases2 = cases.selectAll("rect")
```

The `updateGraph` function did not need to change, i.e., continues to reference only `cases` and not `cases2`.